# How can I write an extendable jQuery class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling to write an HTML templating class that utilizes jquery without wrapping every jquery function. I know the best course when using jquery, and wanting to inherit its methods, is to write a jquery plugin. However, I want to be able to extend the plugin (if that's the method I must take). Currently this is what I have designed using classes.

```
class Templater extends jQuery.fn.init {
    constructor(options){
        super();
        var defaults = {
            template : null,
            // jquery elements for components
            struct : {
                wrapper : ''
            }
        };
        this.settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        this.$wrapper = null;

        return this;
    }

    template(){
        if(this.settings.template === null)
            this.useDefaultTemplate();
        else
            this.useTemplate();
        this.init(this.$wrapper);
        return this;
    }

    useTemplate(){
        var $template = this.settings.template;
        $template = $('<div></div>').append($template);    
        // search for the HTML components
        var self = this;
        $.each(this.settings.struct, function(i, e){
            self['$' + i] = $template.find(e);
        });

        return this;
    }

    useDefaultTemplate() {
        // implement in child
        return this;
    }
}
```

The objective of this class is to take a jquery template (in full code there is support for string) that represents some re-usable HTML element that can be built and used over and over, like a forum post or comment.

```
buildPosts(data){
    // some class called Post extends Templater
    var post = new Post($('#postTemplate'));
    $.each(data, function(i, e){
        post.addPost(e).appendTo('table');
    });
}
```

While there are other ways to do the above, the point is `Templater` would be extended by other classes, like a table generator with more functionality (manage data, add rows, update rows, etc).

The point of inheriting jQuery would be to inherit its great DOM controls, like `appendTo`, `remove`, etc. By inheriting jQuery and calling `this.init()` this actually somewhat works. But it has major flaws. It seems call the constructor when `appendTo` is called, for instance.

I've tried to use the plugin method, but if you call

`var template = new $().Templater(options).template().appendTo('body')`

`template` ends up as a jquery object (because the last call is to appendTo) and now no non-jquery functions are useable.

Is there any sensible way to do this, or should I just wrap the jquery functions in my `Templater` class?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to complicate creating a plugin like this. When you extend `$.fn` you automatically get the element collection passed into your plugin function and when you return `this.each` you can chain other jQuery methods

Comment: Exactly, but I cannot chain non-jquery methods.

Comment: So as you suggested you extend the plugin

Comment: If I use `$.fn` to write a plugin, and add methods like`this.something = function()` and I return `this`, I can chain jQuery functions. But if I call a jquery function such as `appendTo` which returns something more like `$(this)`, I cannot chain my own non-jquery returning functions..

Comment: But what do those functions do and why can't they be `$.fn` functions also or internal methods within plugin that you identify using paramters?

Comment: The problem I ran into with both approaches is (plugin or extend with a class) is that I can't chain a jquery function and my own internal method because the internal methods don't return jquery. And if they did, I could no longer operate on `this`

Comment: But there are numerous ways to use methods in plugins. Or create a different `$.fn`. Would really help if you explained what you are trying to make plugin do at a higher level

Comment: For example you could have internal method that you call with `$(selector).foo().foo('add',1,2)`. In plugin would just check what arguments are and call `function add(){}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116896/discussion-between-tester232323-and-charlietfl).